# Void pointer to various classes in c++

Tags: c++

**Background:**

1. I come from a C background and just started using C++ for embedded projects.
2. I have written a single firmware that is able to handle multiple devices, depending on how it is configured via a graphical interface before the end user gets the device.
3. Each device type is represented by a class.
4. Many parameters are shared across multiple (but not all) types of devices (i.e. battery level), and some functions as well (i.e. read something from EEPROM which is device-type specific).

**Goal:**

To be able to access functions and variables through a pointer without having to cast the void pointer constantly.

**Shouldn't I know what type of device I am using before calling a function?**

Well yes I do, but let's consider the following.

```
void * _type;
uint8_t deviceType = getDeviceTypeFromEEPROM();

//somewhere at the beginning
switch(deviceType)
{
        case DEVICE_A:
            _type = new DeviceA();
            break;
        case DEVICE_B:
            _type = new DeviceB();
            break;
}

//somewhere during execution. 
//I want to avoid having to do something like this. 2 types in example, in reality I have over 10. 
//I would prefer not to put a switch and cast every time I need flexibility.
switch(deviceType)
{
        case DEVICE_A:
            static_cast<DeviceA*>(_type)->readEEPROM();
            break;

        case DEVICE_B:
            static_cast<DeviceB*>(_type)->readEEPROM();
            break;
}
```

**Contemplated Solution:**

Have a base class and using virtual functions. What about variables? Would I need to have virtual functions to access the variables that reside in the different classes?

**Other Solutions:**

Open to any alternative solutions.

Comment: is `deviceType` a compiletime constant?

Comment: This is kind of a big question. We would need to examine all the classes and their behaviors and invariants before deciding the best approach (polymorphism, visitor pattern, templating, or some combination)

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Sorry, I will edit the code and comment that portion. It is something that is stored during the initial configuration and saved in non-volatile memory

Comment: I think you need to start this project off by learning about OOP. AndyG’s correct comment notwithstanding, this is somewhat of a solved problem (OOP might not actually be the *best* solution in modern C++, but it’s well established, battle-tested, and conceptually relatively simple).

Comment: `Would I need to have virtual functions to access the variables that reside in the different classes?` well yes / no / depends. If they are commonly shared by all subclasses you can e.g. pass them in the constructor to the base class from the child class (e.g. as a constant argument) and store them in the base class as regular member.

Comment: This looks like a textbook-example OOP use case.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of how I might implement an OOP-style solution; nothing fancy, just an enumeration of the different types of parameter your program supports, and an `IDevice` interface that represents any device that knows how to set or get values of those types.  Then you can implement subclasses as necessary for devices with parameters that are specific to that device type:

```
enum class ParameterType {
   BatteryLevel,
   Uptime,
   SerialNumber,
   DeviceAProprietarySetting,
   DeviceBProprietarySetting,
   // [... add more values here as necessary...]
};

typedef std::variant<int, float, std::string> ParameterValue;

// Abstract interface to any device 
// (so you can pass around IDevice* pointers instead of void* pointers)
class IDevice
{
public:
   IDevice() {}
   virtual ~IDevice() {}

   /** Subclass should implement this to write the specified parameter-value
     * into (retValue) and return true... or if it cannot (e.g. because it
     * doesn't support that particular parameter-value), it should return
     * false to indicate failure.
     */
   virtual bool GetValue(ParameterType pt, ParameterValue & retValue) const = 0;

   /** Subclass should implement this to accept the specified parameter-value
     * from (newValue) and return true... or if it cannot (e.g. because it
     * doesn't support that particular parameter-value), it should return
     * false to indicate failure to set anything.
     */
   virtual bool SetValue(ParameterType pt, const ParameterValue & newValue) = 0;

   // more virtual methods could be added here, if there are other actions
   // that most of your devices support
};

// Since most devices have these parameters, we'll move them up into a shared
// base class to avoid having to reimplement that functionality for every device
class TypicalDevice : public IDevice
{
   TypicalDevice() {}

   virtual bool GetValue(ParameterType pt, ParameterValue & retValue) const
   {
      switch(pt)
      {
         case ParameterType::BatteryLevel: retValue = _batteryLevel; return true;
         case ParameterType::Uptime:       retValue = _uptime;       return true;
         case ParameterType::SerialNumber: retValue = _serialNumber; return true;
         default:                          return false;  // ParameterType not found!
      }
   }

   virtual bool SetValue(ParameterType pt, const ParameterValue & newValue)
   {
      switch(pt)
      {
         case ParameterType::BatteryLevel: _batteryLevel = std::get<float>(newValue);       return true;
         case ParameterType::Uptime:       _uptime;      = std::get<int>(newValue)          return true;
         case ParameterType::SerialNumber: _serialNumber = std::get<std::string>(newValue); return true;
         default:                          return false;  // ParameterType not found!
      }
   }

private:
   float _batteryLevel;
   int _uptime;  // in seconds?
   std::string _serialNumber;
};

// Implementation for some specific device-type
class DeviceA : public TypicalDevice
{
   DeviceA() {}

   virtual bool GetValue(ParameterType pt, std::variant & retValue) const
   {
      switch(pt)
      {
         case ParameterType::DeviceAProprietarySetting: retValue = _deviceAProprietarySetting; return true;

         default:
            return TypicalDevice::GetValue(pt, retValue);
      }
   }

   virtual bool SetValue(ParameterType pt, const std::variant & newValue)
   {
      switch(pt)
      {
         case ParameterType::DeviceAProprietarySetting: _deviceAProprietarySetting = std::get<float>(newValue); return true;

         default:
            return TypicalDevice::GetValue(pt, retValue);
      }
   }

private:
   float _deviceAProprietarySetting;
};
```

Comment: Overridden function should be marked `override` instead of `virtual` to avoid confusion